# Сравнение минимального числа из четырех чисел

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, как программа понимает, как вычисляется min(c,d); ведь это не прописано, а прописано только какое число будет минимальным из min(a,b), тем не менее, программа работает корректно.

```
public static int min(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    if (min(a, b) < min(c, d)) {
        return min(a, b);
    } else {
        return min(c, d);
    }
}
public static int min(int a, int b) {
    if (a < b) 
        return a;
    else 
        return b;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это разные a,b .. Может так будет понятнее?

```
public static int min(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
  if (min(a,b) < min(c,d)) {  // вызываем по очереди min(e,f) с параметрами e = a, f = b и e = c, f = d
      return min(a,b);
  } else  {
    return min(c,d);
  }
}

public static int min(int e, int f) {
  if (e < f)
    return e;
  else
    return f;
}
```

Тут две разные функции, одна с четыремя параметрами, другая с двумя. Та что с четыремя вызывает несколько раз ту что с двумя.

```
min(1,2) -> 1
min(1,2,3,4) ->   min(1,2) < min(3,4) ? min(1,2) : min(3,4)  -> 1
```

Comment: можно еще верхнюю переписать в одну строчку: return min(min(a,b), min(c,d));